# How to extract the data from a json and store it accordingly?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So i'm doing an API call and it will return something like this

```
"info": {
     "id": 15,
     "status": "on-going",
     "user_id": 10,
     "data": "[{"position":"{\"X\":\"3\",\"Y\":\"56\",\"Z\":\"90\"}","status":"not-found"},{"position":"{\"X\":\"9\",\"Y\":\"46\",\"Z\":\"45\"}","status":"not-found"},{"position":"{\"x\":90,\"Y\":4,\"Z\",\"44\"}","status":"not-found"},{"position":"{\"x\":80,\"Y\":10,\"Z\",\"0\"}","status":"not-found"}]"
    }
```

I would like to extract values in "data" into either a List of some sort. I'm thinking the list would be like (maybe there's a better way?)

```
List position
X:3,Y:56,Z:90
X:9,Y:46,Z:45
etc

List status
not-found
not-found
etc
```

Then im going to use those 2 lists, find the same index and assign. Anyway, i currently have the call like this

```
if (cd.result.ToString() != "no data")
{
    createResponse = JsonUtility.FromJson<CreateResponse>(cd.result.ToString());

    string str = createResponse.game.data.ToString();
}

[Serializable]
public class Game
{
    public string id;
    public string status;
    public string data;
    public string user_id;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that json is valid? Also what's your actual question/problem?

Comment: @pixlhero well, that's what's returned. i wanna extract those values in "data" into separate lists. i was thinking maybe remove the []{}"", change the comma in the position to something else, then Split() by comma, then Add wtv was found to lists.

Comment: I would follow Teemu's answer with Newtonsoft, because Unity's JsonUtility is a bit restrictive. Do you have any power over the API? Cause that json doesn't look that nice.

Comment: @pixlhero okay, will try. no i don't but i could suggest to pic?

Comment: Your json is not valid , fix info.data at first. It is easier to do at API side.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how unitys JsonUtility works but here is how this should go in Newtonsoft json which is a nuget package for .Net, I guess that unitys json-package will work almost the same way:

```
Game test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>("json here");

public class CreateResponse
{
    public Game info{ get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public string id;
    public string status;
    public List<Coord> data { get; set; }
    public int user_id;
}

public class Coord
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```